# How do you add a permenant banner or link?

Tags: slack

I've set up a slack for a large group to work collectively on a number of tasks, foremost amongst them editing a Google Doc. Most of the participants aren't very tech savvy, and even using Google Docs has been something of a challenge - but I still think it's preferrable to endless emails and versions.

My problem is that they keep losing the link to the Google Doc. I've put it in a pinned post, but that's still something they need to 'look for'. Is there some way to permenantly affix a hyperlink, so that they can't miss it? Something like a banner, or a 'more-than-pinned' post?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the link as a topic of the channel maybe.